# Import all txt files in folder, concatenate into data frame, use file names as variable in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, import, append

I have a folder with 142 tab-delimited text files. Each file has 19 variables, and then a number of rows beneath (usually no more than 30 rows, but it varies).
I want to do several things with these files in R automatically, and I can't seem to get exactly what I want with my code. I am new to loops, I got both sections of code from previous posts here at stackoverflow but can't seem to figure out how to combine their functions.

1. I want to turn the filename into a variable when reading the files into R, so that each row has the identifying file name
2. Concatenate all files (with filename variable and no header) into one dataframe with dimensions Yx19, where Y=however many resulting rows there are.

I am able to create a list of the 142 dataframes using this code:

```
myFiles = list.files(path="~/Documents/ForR/", pattern="*.txt")
data <- lapply(myFiles, read.table, sep="\t", header=FALSE)
names(data) <- myFiles
    for(i in myFiles) 
    data[[i]]$Source = i
    do.call(rbind, data)
```

I am able to create the dataframe I want with 19 variables, but the filename is not present:

```
files <- list.files(path="~/Documents/ForR/.", pattern=".txt")
    DF <- NULL
        for (f in files) {
        dat <- read.csv(f, header=F, sep="\t", na.strings="", colClasses="character")
        DF <- rbind(DF, dat)
    }
```

How do I add the file name (without .txt if possible) as a variable to the loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add to the loop 
    dat$file <- unlist(strsplit(f,split=".",fixed=T))[1]

```
files <- list.files(path="~/Documents/ForR/.", pattern=".txt")
    DF <- NULL
        for (f in files) {
        dat <- read.csv(f, header=F, sep="\t", na.strings="", colClasses="character")
        dat$file <- unlist(strsplit(f,split=".",fixed=T))[1]
        DF <- rbind(DF, dat)
    }
```

Shouldn't the row.names from the do.call be in the format names(list)[n].i where i is 1:number_of_rows_for_data.frame n? so you can just make a column from the row.names

```
data <- lapply(myFiles, read.table, sep="\t", header=FALSE)
combined.data <- do.call(rbind, data)
combined.data$file_origin <- row.names(combined.data)
```

Comment: Do note that this can be very slow when the number of files is very large. Each time `DF` is extended, new memory is allocated and the content is copied from the old memory to the new memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `basename` to get the last path element( filename) , for example:

```
 (files = file.path("~","Documents","ForR",c("file1.txt", "file2.txt")))
 "~/Documents/ForR/file1.txt" "~/Documents/ForR/file2.txt"

(basename(files))
[1] "file1.txt" "file2.txt"
```

Then `sub` to remove  the extension ".txt":

```
 sub('.txt','',basename(files),fixed=TRUE)
[1] "file1" "file2"
```