# Generate unique dataframe from list of dataframes with merge

Tags: r, list, for-loop, merge

I have read somewhere how to read multiple txt files into a big list, but I am not able to create a single data.frame with all elements of the list and change the name of the columns so they include a prefix with the name pf the variable.

My case is not the exact same as here:
[Import all txt files in folder, concatenate into data frame, use file names as variable in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107006/import-all-txt-files-in-folder-concatenate-into-data-frame-use-file-names-as-v)

I have 23 txt files. All of them have 18 variables. some have 1842 observations, some have 1830. All text file have a colum called LABEL which has a unique ID for the same sites. This column is ideal for doing a merge:
 `merge(x,y, by="LABEL")`

I would like to do the following:

1. Read all txt files into a big list
2. The name of the files have a suffix designating "summary statistics", e.g., "elevation_st" that I would like to eliminate. I know how to use gsub to eliminate the suffix from the list of files.

`var.list <- list.files(path=getwd(), pattern="_st") ## list of text files
data <- lapply(var.list, rad.table, sep=",", header=TRUE ## Create a big list with all data.frames, each for a variable
names(data) <- gsub("_st", "", var.list) ## eliminate the suffix "_st"`

3. Append a prefix. I know how to do it for one data.frame, but not as a loop :(

`colnames(data$alt_channel) <- paste("alt_channel", colnames(alt_channel), sep="_")`

Whenever I try to do a loop, I end up only with the last element of the list as "i", I know I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what:

`list <- as.vector(names(data)
for (i in list) {
colnames(i) <- paste("i", colnames(i), sep="_")`
}`

I obtain an error message:
"Error in colnames <- (*tmp*, value="i_"):
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions"

And I am stuck here, but I would like to do:

4. Combine all columns into a single data.frame by the column LABEL (merge?)
5. Can I do this with a loop?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know how to use this code since for each element of the list it is a new variable, alt_channel was just the first. But I know it can be something similar.

Comment: lapply(data, function(x) {colnames(x) <- paste('x', colnames(x), sep="_") ;x}) adds and x to all the variables independently of the dataframe name :(

Comment: it is a List of 23, but again it gives the same error (attempt to set colnames on an object with less than two dimmensions). I am doing it manually. I would still appreciate help merging them into a single dataframe, though

Comment: Okay, now I understand what you are trying to do. You wanted to prefix with the name of the list element instead of a constant one.

Comment: exactly. And the thing get even more complicated because I need to leave one column within each dataframe as it is, so I can merge all of them afterwards.

Comment: Perhaps  `lapply(seq_along(data), function(i) {colnames(data[[i]])[-1] <- paste(names(data)[i], colnames(data[[i]])[-1], sep="_"); data[[i]]})`. Assuming that you want to leave the first column as it is.. The data is `set.seed(24);
 data <- list( data.frame(Col1=1:5, Col2=6:10), data.frame(Col1=10:20, Col2=30:40));
names(data) <- LETTERS[1:2]`

Comment: it said "Error in data[[i]]: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: based on my example data it works.  You haven't provided any example or `st(data)` or dput

Comment: the last element:                                                                                                                                     `$ uranium_st     :'data.frame': 1830 obs. of  18 variables:
  ..$ zone          : int [1:1830] 18001 18002 18003 18004 18005 18006 18007 18008 18009 18010 ...
  ..$ label         : int [1:1830] 18001 18002 18003 18004 18005 18006 18007 18008 18009 18010 ...
  ..$ non_null_cells: int [1:1830] 1440 1530 1600 1187 2452 1166 945 2198 2366 2152 ...
  ..$ null_cells    : int [1:1830] 0 0 0 0 0 167 0 0 0 0 ...`

Comment: It is a little difficult to understand from the comments.  Seems like you have both `data.frame` and `vectors` (as I originally menioned) in your list elements

Comment: List of 23
 $ alt_channel_st :'data.frame': 1842 obs. of  18 variables:
  ..$ zone          : int [1:1842] 18001 18002 18003 18004 18005 18006 18007 18008 18009 18010 ...

Comment: yes. I may just do it one by one. And merge the dataframes one by one. I am not good saving time with loops, but since I don't know how to write code, I waste even more time!

Comment: Best is creating a small reproducible example that mimics your dataset (just like I showed with an example) and your expected result.  Here, if you have a vector as a list element, may be you can skip those with `data1 <- data[!sapply(data, is.vector)]`